# Is there a way in R to filter a data frame by two sequential conditions?

Tags: r, filter, conditional-statements, sequential

I have a dataframe that represents the results of Pearson's correlation. This is a sample of the structure:

```
Row     | Column | cor
Event   |Event   | 1
mean    |Event   | .82
mean    |kurtosis| .30
mean    |entropy | .85
entropy |Event   | .71
entropy |kurtois | .25
kurtosis|Event   | .69
```

I need to filter the correlations so if the correlation between two features was larger than the 0.80 (condition 1) threshold, only the variable with the highest association with "Event" is selected (condition 2).
I am hoping the end product will look like this:

```
Row     | Column | cor
mean    |Event   | .82
```

In the example above, mean and entropy are correlated above the threshold, however, "mean" has the higher correlation with "Event" So that is the final output. I am using biological data so I have 100s of features and its too much to do manually.

Comment: what if `cor(kurtosis, Event)` was 0.87 what rows would you have obtained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     filter(Row  != Column, cor > 0.80, Column == 'Event')
```

-output

```
#   Row Column  cor
#1 mean  Event 0.82
```

Or use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[Row!= column & cor > 0.8 & Column == 'Event']
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Row = c("Event", "mean", "mean", "mean", "entropy", 
"entropy", "kurtosis"), Column = c("Event", "Event", "kurtosis", 
"entropy", "Event", "kurtois", "Event"), cor = c(1, 0.82, 0.3, 
0.85, 0.71, 0.25, 0.69)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: This works but takes about 10 times longer in processing time as the base R answer.

Comment: @Baroque Is the timings on a bigger dataset

Comment: This completes the first step, finding correlations that are about 0.80,  but now I need to find which of the results from step 1 has the highest correlation with "Event" That is step 2

Comment: Please take a look at OP expected output. This gives more rows

Answer (score 0):

Like this? The conditions stated do not cover all bases but this gives the desired result for this problem

```
df[df$cor>.8 & df$Column=="Event" & df$Row!="Event",]
```

Comment: `subset(df, Row!=Column & Column == 'Event' & cor>0.8)`

Comment: That works too, and is on the same order of magnitude in terms of processing speed according to `microbenchmark`, though it is slightly slower

Comment: I tried both methods and I get an empty data frame

Comment: That would happen if there's never a row where all of the conditions are TRUE at the same time, since we are using AND (&)